# When to use "confirm" and when to use "continue" and when to use "proceed"?

Tags: word-usage, differences

I have a software program, where the user should confirm an action, which might be dangerous. Which text should I display on that button: *Confirm*, *Continue* or *Proceed*?

Comment: No one can say when you should use (write? pronounce? code?) any word at all without some idea of what you mean to accomplish by doing so.

Comment: @JohnLawler specified the question.

Comment: You shouldn't use a single verb as a display, then. You should use a whole verb phrase like "Confirm that you would like to `<perform action>` anyway" that indicates what's at issue. Single-word responses like "continue" should be avoided.

Comment: @JohnLawler There is a further description provided, it's about the text displayed on the button

Comment: Then the text on the button should use whatever verb is used in the description, so the user will relate the two. Many users don't do this automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Confirm" has a specific meaning that the user has asked you to do that something, and you want them to to specify it again (to be sure that they really did mean it). You ask them to press "Confirm" when they mean "yes, I am sure i want to do that'.

Both "Proceed" and "Continue" mean simply "go ahead to the next step".